# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. Corey Schafer Flask Tutorial

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

i'm trying to understand flask. I'm a newbie.
I made progress up to lesson 4. [youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYWiDiIUxQc&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&ab_channel=CoreySchafer)

Create templates, static-css, bootstrap connections, ORM classes.

When i open the python terminal and

> > > `from flaskblog import db` it is ok, no statement like in the vide, then
> > > `db.create_all()`

this is where my code collapse...

error is exactly as it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/erdoganb/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 884, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "/Users/erdoganb/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 855, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
  File "/Users/erdoganb/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 636, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/Users/erdoganb/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

and tried the add, app.app_context() into my flaskblog.py file.

Can you help me where is my mistake(s)?

Thank you.

and tried the add, app.app_context().push() into my flaskblog.py file. gives me another error

reinstalling some packages, like sqlalchemy

Answer (score 3):

I've solved my problem.

I've added

```
app.app_context().push()
```

then

```
db.create_all()
```

solved my problem.

And also, for creating database and initialize, you can just run your code without the codes above, get in directory then open a python terminal (repl) then

```
from yourapp import *

app.app_context().push()

db.create_all()
```

Second method is more sensible to me.
Because you better check your database in the beginning and don't touch it later.

Answer (score 0):

When your app size grows there will be dependency on multiple library. So for this you should start using Factory Pattern to avoid this issue and organize the project
Here is the documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/appfactories/

Comment: thank you i'll check it while my project grows. and kind of solved my problem, i guess its about the "sqlite::///test.db" and you have be in same folder while running the app. somehow it conflicts with some other program, im not sure but it worked for me. thank you for your suggestion.